# TimeStamp Updates to Adjacent Columns

Tags: google-apps-script

I've was wondering if what to do is possible and how to go about it. This is For Google Sheets. Here is the script I'm using (Found this script and edited it for my use):

```
function onEdit(e) {
var s = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
var cols = [5];
if (s !== 'Michele' && s !== 'Janet' && s !== 'Stephanie' || cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) ==-1 || !e.value) return;
  e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "CST", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"));
}
```

Column 5 (E) has the option to choose different statuses. So far, I have it putting the TimeStamp of Column 5's change in its adjacent column, 6 (F). What I'm trying to figure out is if the status is changed again (Pending -> Confirmed-> Installed-> ect) , instead of updating Column 6, which would already be TimeStamped, it will instead move on to Column  7, then 8, then 9, ect.

Let me know if more detail is needed.

Thanks a Bunch!

Comment: Do you want the timestamp of a certain status to go into a certain column or do you want them to go adjacent in every case?

Comment: I'm thinking adjacent in every case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested this code and it works.  It finds the number of cells to the right of column E that already have values in them, and then calculates what the next empty column is, and writes the new date to the next empty column.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var s = sh.getName();
  var lastCol = sh.getLastColumn(); 
  var cols = [5];
  var startCol = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName('ColumnE').getColumn();
  //In the spreadsheet, name a range that is in the column you want to start at
  if (s !== 'Michele' && s !== 'Janet' && s !== 'Stephanie' || cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) ==-1 || !e.value) return;

  var rowEdited = e.range.getRow(); //Get the row that was edited
  //Start in row edited and column 6, get 1 row and X columns
  var datesInCells = sh.getRange(rowEdited,startCol,1,lastCol - 5).getValues();

  Logger.log('datesInCells: ' + datesInCells);
  Logger.log('datesInCells.length: ' + datesInCells[0].length);

  var numberOfDates = 0;

  for (var i=0;i<datesInCells[0].length;i+=1) {
    if (datesInCells[0][i] !== "") {
      numberOfDates +=1;
    };
  };

  Logger.log('numberOfDates: ' + numberOfDates);

  var colToWriteTo = startCol + numberOfDates;
  var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "CST", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  //var theStatus = sh.getRange(rowEdited, 5).getValue();
  var theStatus = e.value;
  var bothStatusAndDate = newDate + " : " + theStatus;

  sh.getRange(rowEdited,colToWriteTo).setValue(bothStatusAndDate);
};
```

Version two:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var s = sh.getName();
  var lastCol = sh.getLastColumn(); 
  var cols = [5];

  if (s !== 'Michele' && s !== 'Janet' && s !== 'Stephanie' || cols.indexOf(e.range.columnStart) ==-1 || !e.value) return;

  var rowEdited = e.range.getRow(); //Get the row that was edited
  //Start in row edited and column 6, get 1 row and X columns
  var datesInCells = sh.getRange(rowEdited,6,1,lastCol - 5).getValues();

  Logger.log('datesInCells: ' + datesInCells);
  Logger.log('datesInCells.length: ' + datesInCells[0].length);

  var numberOfDates = 0;

  for (var i=0;i<datesInCells[0].length;i+=1) {
    if (datesInCells[0][i] !== "") {
      numberOfDates +=1;
    };
  };

  Logger.log('numberOfDates: ' + numberOfDates);
  var newDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "CST", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
  if (numberOfDates > 4) {
    var existingValues = sh.getRange(rowEdited,7,1,4).getValues();
    sh.getRange(rowEdited,6,1,4).setValues(existingValues);
    sh.getRange(rowEdited,10).setValue(newDate);
    return;
  };

  var colToWriteTo = 6 + numberOfDates;

  sh.getRange(rowEdited,colToWriteTo).setValue(newDate);
};
```

Comment: Awesome. It works great! But, if there are things in any of the columns after Column 5 (Status 1), it puts the time stamp way farther than i need it to go. Here's the link so you can kind off see whats going on. The Michele tab is the one I've been looking at but it does it to all three of those tabs in the script.                                https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CcqoDaI8hy3-hMsb5NRF2j1cipW_JOpEJ-utdY7Tg0s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Okay, so you need it to stop when it gets to column J?  Or stop when it gets to the "Final Status Timestamp"?  And what then?  Start overwriting dates back at the beginning?

Comment: I would like for it to stop when it gets to "Final Status TimeStamp". If its possible, at that point it should start overwriting back at "Status 1 TimeStamp". If it can't work that way, that's alright, the admins won't be able to see the Timestamp since they are for my eyes only so I could always add more columns for timestamps if need be. I also have another question that might be a bit of a stretch. When the status is changed, is it possible to have that status appear along with the date in the timestamp Columns?     Again, thank you for all the help.

Comment: Well, if you start back at the beginning, then the dates will be out of order.  Before the dates get to the end, there will be older and older dates to the right.  If you start back at the beginning, there will be an earlier date after a later date.  Plus, for ease of programming it, it would be better to shift everything to the left, and always put the oldest date at the end.

Comment: That makes more sense to shift everything to the left. Would it be easier to have the timestamps start on Column CS since there will be no other info added after that point?

Comment: If you wanted to add all the time stamps starting in column CS, and didn't care how long it got, all you'd need to do is change the line of code:  `var colToWriteTo = 6 + numberOfDates;` **TO:** `var colToWriteTo = 97 + numberOfDates;`  Change the number 6 to 97.

Comment: I added a version to shift data to the left.  I did not test it.  The parameters may need to be adjusted.

Comment: In the spreadsheet, you can name a range, and then get the column of that range with `var startCol = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName('ColumnE').getColumn();`  If you consider my answer the correct answer, you can mark it as correct.  You get points for marking the correct answer.

Comment: Tried the new script. the date came up as undefined so. Put the date stuff in there. Still weirdly offsetting. not entirely sure where to put that new line.

Comment: The line for `newDate` needed to be moved up.  I did that.  Is my answer helpful?  Do you consider it to be the correct answer?

Comment: Yes it Was and Absolutely. One last thing, When the status is picked, is it possible to have that as well as the date as the timestamp so that i could see past changes as well as the date it was changed to?

Comment: If the status is in the column that triggered the code to run, then all you need to do is use:  `var status = e.value;`  I added a couple new lines of code to the first example.  Then you need to concatenate the status and the data.  In JavaScript string concatenation is done with a plus sign.

Comment: Awesome, absolutely perfect. Thank you!